# Getting logo to appear to the right of navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm using Bootstrap 4.2.1 and having issues trying to get the brand to appear to the right of my navbar. It's appearing just where I want it in a small viewport -- to the right of the hamburger -- but when expanded to a larger viewport, the logo appears to the left of the navbar items.  I've tried using navbar-right, pull-right, float: right,  placing the logo code in various spots in the navbar code, but I can't get it to appear on the right of the menu.

I'm probably missing something obvious, but any suggestions on how to get the logo to appear on the right? [Here's the page](http://test.scoe.net/sccy2/). And below is an example of the code.

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-custom">
  <div class="mx-auto d-lg-flex d-block flex-lg-nowrap">
    <!-- menu/hamburger button -->
    <button aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" class="navbar-toggler custom-toggler" data-target="#navbarsExample11" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">Menu <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button> 
    <!-- logo -->
    <a class="navbar-brand navbar-right" href="index.html"><img alt="CCFAC logo" height="42" src="images/logoSM.png"></a> 
    <!-- end logo -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center" id="navbarsExample11">
      <ul class="navbar-nav align-items-center">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" class="nav-link dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" id="navbarDropdown1" role="button">For Teens</a>
          <div aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown4" class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="marijuanaPrevention.html">Marijuana Prevention</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="alcoholPrevention.html">Alcohol Prevention</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" class="nav-link dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" id="navbarDropdown2" role="button">For Parents</a> <span class="caret"></span>
          <div aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown4" class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="marijuanaPrevention.html">Marijuana Prevention</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="alcoholPrevention.html">Alcohol Prevention</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="partners.html">For Teachers</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" class="nav-link dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" id="navbarDropdown4" role="button">Our Initiatives</a>
          <div aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown4" class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="futureForward.html">Future Forward</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="talkTheyHearYou.html">Talk. They Hear You.</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" class="nav-link dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" id="navbarDropdown5" role="button">Media</a>
          <div aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown4" class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://sacramentoccy.smugmug.com" target="_blank">Photos</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC5IR7O7WLAA8I-fHUfEYFXw" target="_blank">Videos</a> 
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.facebook.com/SacramentoCCY/" target="_blank">Facebook</a> 
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Instagram</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="calendar.html">Calendar</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="aboutUs.html">About Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Right now, your logo resolves after the hamburger button, but before your menu.  You'll just have to have the logo resolve last.

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-custom">
  <div class="mx-auto d-lg-flex d-block flex-lg-nowrap">
    <!-- menu/hamburger button -->
    <button aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" class="navbar-toggler custom-toggler" data-target="#navbarsExample11" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">Menu <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button> 

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center" id="navbarsExample11">
      <ul class="navbar-nav align-items-center">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" class="nav-link dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" id="navbarDropdown1" role="button">For Teens</a>
          <div aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown4" class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="marijuanaPrevention.html">Marijuana Prevention</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="alcoholPrevention.html">Alcohol Prevention</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" class="nav-link dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" id="navbarDropdown2" role="button">For Parents</a> <span class="caret"></span>
          <div aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown4" class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="marijuanaPrevention.html">Marijuana Prevention</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="alcoholPrevention.html">Alcohol Prevention</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="partners.html">For Teachers</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" class="nav-link dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" id="navbarDropdown4" role="button">Our Initiatives</a>
          <div aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown4" class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="futureForward.html">Future Forward</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="talkTheyHearYou.html">Talk. They Hear You.</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" class="nav-link dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" id="navbarDropdown5" role="button">Media</a>
          <div aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown4" class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://sacramentoccy.smugmug.com" target="_blank">Photos</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC5IR7O7WLAA8I-fHUfEYFXw" target="_blank">Videos</a> 
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.facebook.com/SacramentoCCY/" target="_blank">Facebook</a> 
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Instagram</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="calendar.html">Calendar</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="aboutUs.html">About Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- logo -->
    <a class="navbar-brand navbar-right" href="index.html"><img alt="CCFAC logo" height="42" src="images/logoSM.png"></a> 
    <!-- end logo -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried it, and unfortunately, with a small viewport, the logo disappears into the drop-down menu items. Clicking on the hamburger, you can find the logo at the bottom of the list of menu items.  You can see it in action here: http://test.scoe.net/sccy3/

Comment: My fault - I misplaced the logo in my example code.  I've fixed it, please try again...  The concept is correct, you just need the logo to resolve after the navbar html, the div with the id "navbarsExample11"